# Can any one explain the working of the certain part of the given circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier, frequency

its a circuit describing f to v converter[image: frew]

what happens when the switch is closed by the monostable multivibrator ie( one-shot) ,drawing out 1mA current from the summing junction.

---

Text in book

on each negative spike of V1 ,CMp triggers the one shot ,closing SW and pulling 1mA out of C1 for a duration Th.**In response to this train of current pulses ,Vo builds up until the current pulled out of the summing junction of OA in 1-mA packets is exactly counterbalanced by that injected by vo via R continuously** .
can somebody help me to understand this bold text

Answer (score 1):

R wants to discharge C1 to 0.  Each time the one shot fires the current source get integrated for for the one shot on time.  This raises Vo.  At a fixed frequency the increase in during the one shot on time will equal the decrease during the off time.  The average of this waveform is a function of frequency.  If the frequency is increased, the capacitor will charge the same amount during the one shot on time, but will discharge less because of reduced time between triggers. This will raise the average voltage.